# Can't map a range of dates in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to map a range of dates and pass them to my view as an array, as follows:

```
from, to = Date.parse("2014-01-01"), Date.yesterday
date_range = (from..to)

@mapped_dates = date_range.map {|date| date.strftime("%b %e")}
```

I reference them in some JS in my view as follows:

```
dateLabels = <%= raw @mapped_dates.to_json %>;
```

When I visit the page, I get the following error:

```
can't iterate from ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

The strange thing is, I can run the Ruby in the Rails console, and it returns what I expect: `["Jan 1", "Jan 2", "Jan 3", ... ]`

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this error?

Comment: Are you sure issue is with this code on your page? It works for me

Comment: Aside: consider `date_range = Date.parse("2014-01-01")..Date.yesterday`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
 dateLabels = <%= raw @mapped_dates.as_json %>;
```

This will return

```
 ["Jan 1", "Jan 2", "Jan 3", ... ]
```

For `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` problem, please do -

In config/initializers/time_zone.rb

```
  class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
    def as_json(options = {})
      if ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.use_standard_json_time_format
        xmlschema
      else
        %(#{time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")} #{formatted_offset(false)})
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the wrong array to your view. It should be:

```
dateLabels = <%= raw @mapped_dates.to_json %>;
```

Comment: D'oh... That was a typo. Edited the original post.